# unix sendmail, Header content is shown into body part

Tags: linux, email, message, sendmail

I am using Linux senmail utility to send out emails,
I use below command to send mail `cat headerFile BodyFile | sendmail -t`
which works fine and i get mails successfully.
But,in mail my Header content `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` is shown into Body part.
Do you have any idea why Header is included into body part.

Comment: Do you have a newline at the end of the headers file?

Comment: Yes, But i think it shouldn't make any difference